# vscode debugging multiple files in the same folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am new to C++ and vscode. I know how to run the vscode debugger on a single .cc file but I don't know how to run it on a folder with multiple .h and .cc files (I have Makefile and linking is working). My current solution is to copy and paste the entire project into one file and then run the debugger which is very inefficient.

I suspect that I have to modify launch.json, so here is mine. Any tips are appreciated!

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: The instructions on how to fix this to get Visual Studio Code to build an executable from more than 1 source file are here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: I missed that you were not running windows. The linux instructions are here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: Thanks! I edited my launch and tasks.json according to the website and it works now!